# Where can I learn the pros and cons of the various Source Control systems available?

Tags: windows, version-control

I want to compare and contrast the various source control systems out there. Any good references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understanding Version-Control Systems by Eric Raymond: http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/version-control/version-control.html

Answer (score 2):

Version control systems for Linux: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Apps/vcs.html

Answer (score 1):

Some python core developers have recently begun putting together a [document which illustrates various work flows](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0374/) that compare and contrast working with hg, bzr, git and svn.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comparison of numerous SCMs:
http://better-scm.berlios.de/comparison/comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want a theoretical framework for comparing them. It shows most product comparisons (especially those in the named links) are rather incomplete. There is a 5 dimensional model for this:

- version (wanting to change)
- status (life cycle: creating, testing, deploy, retire)
- view (source, architecture, deployment, derivability)
- hierarchy (module, class, method)
- variant (largely similar, describing the differences, product families)

Most systems only handle a few of these dimensions. To handle all five, you have to describe (fix) your development process.

The reference:

Managing design data: the five dimensions of CAD frameworks,configuration management, and product data management.
van den Hamer, P.   Lepoeter, K.
Philips Res., Eindhoven;

This paper appears in: Proceedings of the IEEE
Publication Date: Jan 1996
Volume: 84,  Issue: 1
On page(s): 42-56
ISSN: 0018-9219
References Cited: 26
CODEN: IEEPAD
INSPEC Accession Number: 5175049
Digital Object Identifier: 10.1109/5.476025
Current Version Published: 2002-08-06

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nice [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) on this: