# Easy version control for two-person team

Tags: version-control

What free, web-hosted, non-public version control system is ideal for a small, two-person project (1 programmer, 1 artist)?

It should be as straightforward as possible, plus ideally should have a GUI for Windows.

Comment: version control is a lot about the process and not so much about the tool. if you have a lousy process no tool in the world will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I learn the pros and cons of the various Source Control systems available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474573/where-can-i-learn-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-various-source-control-systems-availa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now trying out the free *subversion* repository on [Assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com).

Together with [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net), this appears to be very straightforward to use. Tortoise integrates seamlessly into Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

BitBucket provides free and private repository facilities both for Git and Mercurial (for up to 5 users).